# Preparação de dados no R para utilização de cluster

Tags: r

Tenho um banco de dados, onde na primeira coluna são alguns times de basquete e as colunas seguintes são algumas variáveis observadas. Gostaria de fazer uma análise de cluster utilizando tais pacotes:

```
library("cluster") ;
library("factoextra") ;
library("magrittr")
```

**Banco de dados:**

[image: Amostra do banco de dados]

Ao ler meu banco de dados que estava em csv, o transformei em data.frame, porém na tentativa de fazer a escala das variáveis com o código abaixo aparece este erro dizendo que minha coluna "Time" deve ser numérico e assim consequentemente não consigo também fazer a matriz de correlação, pois no label aparece alguns número aleatórios, em vez de aparecer o nome dos times.

**ERRO**

```
my_data <- na.omit(my_data)
my_data <- scale(my_data)


Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

**ERRO GRÁFICO CORRELAÇÃO**

```
res.dist <- get_dist(my_data, stand = TRUE, method = "pearson")
fviz_dist(res.dist, gradient = list(low = "#00AFBB", mid = "white", high = "#FC4E07"))
```

[image: GRÁFICO CORRELAÇÃO]

Alguém sabe como resolvo isto?

Comment: Imagens gráficas de dados não são nada úteis pois não podemos testar código com elas. É melhor editar a pergunta com o output de `dput(dados)` ou, se o banco for grande, com `dput(head(dados, 30))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o Rui disse no comentário, a imagem do seus dados não nos ajuda a te ajudar. Quanto a dúvida, a função `scale` precisa que seu banco seja uma matriz numérica. Uma solução é você transformar a coluna com o nome das equipes em nome das linhas:

```
row.names(my_data) <- my_data[,1]
my_data <- my_data[,-1]
```

e depois seguir com o seu código. Provavelmente o segundo erro não vai mais acontecer.

Comment: Essa sugestão sua funcionou e deu certo.

Comment: Que bom que funcionou. Considere [votar e aceitar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) a minha resposta se ela resolveu o seu problema.